# How to extract a specific line out of a text file

Tags: python

I have the code from the attached picture in a .can-file, which is in this case a text file. The task is to open the file and extract the content of the void function. In this case it would be "$LIN::Kl_15 = 1;"[image]

This is what I already got:

```
Masterfunktionsliste = open("C:/.../Masterfunktionsliste_Beispiel.can", "r")
Funktionen = []
Funktionen = Masterfunktionsliste.read() 
Funktionen = Funktionen.split('\n')
print(Funktionen)
```

I receive the following list:

```
['', '', 'void KL15 ein', '{', '\t$LIN::Kl_15 = 1;', '}', '', 'void Motor ein', '{', '\t$LIN::Motor = 1;', '}', '', '']
```

And now i want to extract the `$LIN::Kl_15 = 1;` and the `$LIN::Motor = 1;` line into variables.

Comment: you mean you want like : `motor = 1` ? or the whole line as a string in a specific variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `{` and `}` lines to decide what lines to extract:

```
scope_depth = 0
line_stack = list(reversed(Funktionen))
body_lines = []

while len(line_stack) > 0:
    next = line_stack.pop()
    if next == '{':
        scope_depth = scope_depth + 1
    elif next == '}':
        scope_depth = scope_depth - 1
    else:
        # test that we're inside at lest one level of {...} nesting
        if scope_depth > 0:
            body_lines.append(next)
```

`body_lines` should now have values `['$LIN::Kl_15 = 1;', '$LIN::Motor = 1;']`

Comment: Thanks @Mathias R. Jessen for the answer and I was already using the code but now I want to add a feature: How can I extract the content of only one e.g. from `void KL15 ein` function? The case would be the the function you have shown me would get a variable as input `function = KL15` ein and then returns (in body_lines) the content `'$LIN::Kl_15 = 1'`.

Comment: @Markus you could add an extra variable to keep track of the last line before scope_depth > 0, then exit once you leave the relevant scope again. If you want further guidance/suggestions: please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)

Comment: I have created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73705308/how-to-extract-a-specific-string-out-of-a-list-dependant-on-its-content) and I would be very thankful if you can have a look at it, as created the solution for the first part.

Comment: sorry I forgot the tag @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the list, search for your variables and save it as dict:

```
can_file_content = ['', '', 'void KL15 ein', '{', '\t$LIN::Kl_15 = 1;', '}', '', 'void Motor ein', '{', '\t$LIN::Motor = 1;', '}', '', '']
extracted = {}

for line in can_file_content:
    if "$LIN" in line:  # extract the relevant line
        parsed_line = line.replace(";", "").replace("\t", "")  # remove ";" and "\t"
        variable, value = parsed_line.split("=")  # split on "="
        extracted[variable.strip()] = value.strip()  # remove whitespaces
```

output is `{'$LIN::Kl_15': '1', '$LIN::Motor': '1'}` 
now you can access your new variables with `extracted['$LIN::Motor']` which is `1`