# How to extract a specific string out of a list dependant on it's content

Tags: python, list

I have the following code to extract a "the content of a function" from a list:
This is the list:

```
funktionen = ['testfunction KL15 ein', '{', '$LIN::ZAS_Kl_15 = 1;', '}', '', 'testfunction Motor ein', '{', '$LIN::Motor_laeuft = 1;', '}', 'testfunction Warte_bis', '{', 'write("Warte bis");', '}']
```

The code:

```
line_stack = list(reversed(funktionen))  
content_funk = []
while len(line_stack) > 0:  # gebe Inhalt aus den Funktionen (innerhalb der {...}) aus
    next = line_stack.pop()
    if next == '{':
        scope_depth = scope_depth + 1
    elif next == '}':
        scope_depth = scope_depth - 1
    else:
    # test that we're inside at least one level of {...} nesting
        if scope_depth > 0:
            content_funk.append(next)
```

The result is:

```
content_funk = ['$LIN::ZAS_Kl_15 = 1;', '$LIN::Motor_laeuft = 1;', 'write("Warte bis");']
```

The problem is, that I only want the value of one "function"/value inside {}. So let's say I have a variable `function = Warte_bis` as a input for the code above and the return value should be the content of `testfunction Warte bis` which in this case would be `'write("Warte bis");'`. I hope it is clear what I mean. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand correctly, you try to extract a function content depending on its name.

```
funktionen = ['testfunction KL15 ein', '{', '$LIN::ZAS_Kl_15 = 1;', '}', '', 'testfunction Motor ein', '{', '$LIN::Motor_laeuft = 1;', '}', 'testfunction Warte_bis', '{', 'write("Warte bis");', '}']
scope_depth = 0
line_stack = list(reversed(funktionen))  
content_funk = []
found = False
while len(line_stack) > 0:  # gebe Inhalt aus den Funktionen (innerhalb der {...}) aus
    next = line_stack.pop()
    if "Warte_bis" in next:
        found = True
    if next == '{':
        scope_depth = scope_depth + 1
    elif next == '}':
        scope_depth = scope_depth - 1
    else:
    # test that we're inside at least one level of {...} nesting
        if scope_depth > 0 and found:
            content_funk = next
            found = False
print(content_funk)
```